# is a reduction in free disk space a good overall indicator of a `work_mem` setting that is too low?

Tags: postgresql, performance, memory, memory-management, postgresql-performance

As I understand it (after a fair amount of searching online)...

1- If a component of a query (sort, join, etc.) uses more RAM/memory than my `work_mem` setting *or* the total memory used by all current operations on the server exceeds available OS memory, the query will start writing to disk.

Is that true?

2- Postgres (and many other good DB engines) use memory to cache a lot so queries go faster; therefore, the server *should* indicate low free memory even if the server isn't really *starved* for memory. So low free memory doesn't really indicate anything other than a good DB engine and healthy utilization.

Is that true?

3- If both #1 and #2 above are true, holding everything else content, if I want a board indicator of a `work_mem` setting that is too low or not enough overall OS memory, I should look to see if the server free disk space is going down?

Am I thinking about this correctly?

links:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-resource.html

http://patshaughnessy.net/2016/1/22/is-your-postgres-query-starved-for-memory

https://www.enterprisedb.com/monitor-cpu-and-memory-percentage-used-each-process-postgresqlppas-9

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18484/tuning-postgresql-for-large-amounts-of-ram

I know I can set `log_temp_files` and look at individual temp files to tune the `work_mem` setting, but I wanted an overall gauge I could use to determine if *possibly* `work_mem` is too low before I start digging around looking at temp file sizes that exceed my `work_mem` setting.

I have PostgreSQL 10.

Comment: 1)no 2) the definition of "Free memory" depends on the OS 3) it depends (on the *typical query*)  ,in any case:  free disk space is not a good measure.

Comment: @wildplasser - Thanks! I am surprised by your "no" to #1. Can you give me a one liner explanation to point me in the right direction for searching online?

Comment: Reread your first and forth link. (and ignore the second one, it is nonsense, at least on unix)

Comment: @wildplasser - thanks again. Sadly, I have read all of those links. Not saying I understood it all, but I have read them. I think you are indicating that "it's more complicated than your OQ" rather than "you are missing key point ________". If so, can you provide a for-instance reason #1 is wrong? If not, can you name the key point I am missing? thanks/sorry. I am more Finance guy than Developer guy.

Comment: Reduction in free disk space is a bad indicator. Temp tables are typically 10...100MB is size, and will be cleaned up at the end of the transaction. Very large files can occur if some query (accidently) creates a Carthesian product. In that case you'll notice ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Processing a query takes a number of steps:

1. generate (all)possible plans
2. estimate the cost of execution of these plans (in terms of resources: disk I/O,buffers,memory,CPU), based on tuning constants and statistics.
3. pick the "optimal" plan , based on tuning constants
4. execute the chosen plan.

In most cases, a plan that is expected (step2) to need more work_mem than your work_mem setting will not be chosen in step3. (because "spilling to disk" is considered very expensive)
Once step4 detects that it is needing more work_mem, its only choice is to spill to disk. Shit happens... At least this doesn't rely on the OS's page-swapping the the overcommitted memory.)

The rules are very simple:

- hash-joins are often optimal but will cost memory
- don't try to use more memory than you have
- if there is a difference between expected(step2) and observed(step4) memory, your statistics are wrong. You will be punished by spill-to-disk.
- a lack of usable indexes will cause hash joins or seqscans.
- sorting uses work_mem, too. The mechanism is similar :bad estimates yield bad plans.
- CTE's are often/allways(?) materialized. This will splill to disk once your bufferspace overflows.
- CTE's don't have statistics, and don't have indices.

A few guidelines/advice:

- use a correct data model (and don't denormalize)
- use the correct PK/FK's and secundary indices.
- run `ANALYZE the_table_name;` to gather fresh statistics after huge modifications to the table's structure or data.

Monitoring:

- check the Postgres logfile
- check the query plan, compare observed <--> expected
- monitor the system resource usage (on Linux: via top/vmstat/iostat)

Comment: I don't think there is any site that describes your points 1-4 and the paragraph after them anywhere else on the internet, at least no where that does it as succinctly using plain language. Thank you!